# ResourceExhaustedError: Keras with Tensorflow while training CNN on EyePACS dataset for batch size of just 8 on (768, 768) sized images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Before diving to code, here is my laptop specs:

- Windows 10 Pro GPU
- GTX 970M (3GB VRAM)
- i7 6700HQ with 16GB RAM (If
  at all it matters)

Software versions

- Python 3.6.2
- Tensorflow 1.5.0
- Keras 2.1.3

The paper I am trying to replicate - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050916311929

My code -

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu', input_shape=(768, 768, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=1024, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(units=5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 8

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/Downloads/EyePACS_crop/',target_size=(768, 768),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)

model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=35126//batch_size,
                  epochs=50)
model.save_weights('npdr.h5')
```

I cannot understand why. Even with 3GB VRAM (Tensorflow shows 2.47GB free VRAM) I cannot use a batch size of even 8 images without getting ResourceExhaustedError. The complete output of the program(showing each chunk allocation. I'm suspecting a severe memory leak) is here on pastebin - https://pastebin.com/dRx54brC.

If someone could help me with this, I would be grateful. If it's a bug with keras/tensorflow, I can switch to another framework immediately

Thanks

Comment: In simple words, your images are too big. Normally for CNNs 300x300 and smaller are used, you have images that are more than 4 times that area.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I agree. But reducing the dimension any further means losing fine grain data, inturn taking a hit on accuracy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Get a GPU with more RAM, reduce the batch size, or train on CPU (with more RAM).